# Visual Studio Error/Exception while trying to load a texture in SFML: Access violation reading position 0x00200000

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sfml

I'm trying to load a texture in SFML, however if I run the program, it throws the access violation exception. In relation to this I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034947/c-sfml-text-class-unhandled-exception-at-0x0f58155f-sfml-graphics-d-2-dll) post, but since noone has answered that, I still have no idea what's wrong.

I'm developing on a Win10 PC with Visual Studio 2017 installed. I've already tried changing the location of the files and even putting the files into the debug folders.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Image image;
    if (!image.loadFromFile("board.png")) 
    { 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I expect the program to load the image from the file into memory, instead Visual Studio shows me this exception:

```
Exception raised at 0x716C2CE7 (vcruntime140.dll) in Chess.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00700000.
```

Comment: Note that [`sf::Image::loadFromFile`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a9e4f2aa8e36d0cabde5ed5a4ef80290b) returns `true` if successful; presumably you don't want to `return -1` in this case.

Comment: Also, visual studio should show you the line where the error was raised.  (You may need to move to a different part of the stack trace, which can be found in a dropdown near the top of the window.)  And if it doesn't, start putting breakpoints and stepping through your code to see exactly where the error is.  I don't see any immediate red flags, but if you include more info about the source of the error (or better yet, a [mcve],) it will be easier to help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add an '!' infront of `image.loadFromFile("board.png")`, the error was raised exactly in that line